# how to get position of Edittext in RelativeLayout or alternate method for getY()

Tags: android, position, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I am trying to set my EditTest on specific position in RelativeLayout. So i am getting position of Ediitext and set according what i want. It's working fine with me. But problem is occur when Android 2.2 and android 2.3 devices didn't find `getY()` method. because i am trying to get the position of Ediitext.

Now i need to find another method for this because it's not working in 2.2 and 2.3.

Here is my code for reference.

```
ViewTreeObserver autoCompleteObserver = myAutoComplete.getViewTreeObserver();
    autoCompleteObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {              
            relativeLayoutHeight = ((int) myAutoComplete.getY()-12);
        }
    });   

 activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
            Log.i("TEST", "GLOBAL LAYOUT "+activityRootView.getHeight());
            Log.i("TEST", "GLOBAL LAYOUT rel"+relativeLayoutHeight);
            if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                Log.i("TEsT","Keyboard visible");
                myRelativLayout.scrollTo(0, relativeLayoutHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("TEsT","Keyboard not visible");
                myRelativLayout.scrollTo(0, 0);
                myAutoComplete.setDropDownHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
         }
    });
}
```

This code working fine in 4.1 but i need to find alternate method for `getY()` which return me position of EditText.
Give me any reference or hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `getY()` method from View class in android 4.1: [Link](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java/?v=source)

```
/**
 * The visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the
 * 'translationY' property plus the current
 * 'top' property.
 *
 * @return The visual y position of this view, in pixels.
 */

public float getY() {
    return mTop + 
           (mTransformationInfo != null ? mTransformationInfo.mTranslationY : 0);
}
```

On Android 2.2 & 2.3, there's a similar method called `getTop()`: [Link](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/View.java/?v=source)

```
/**
 * Top position of this view relative to its parent.
 *
 * @return The top of this view, in pixels.
 */

public final int getTop() {
    return mTop;
}
```

So, if you are not applying any translations to your EditText (using `View#setTranslationY(float)` etc.), `getY()` and `getTop()` will provide essentially the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code inside your `onGlobalLayout`

```
int[] locations = new int[2];
yourView.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
int x = locations[0];
int y = locations[1];//returns Y position
```

Comment: not error. but when i was using getY(); then it's showing edittext on proper location but if i use this code then it will show good on one screen but it will not showing proper on other scree. Means no compatibility.

Comment: Then use `View.getTop()` and `View.getLeft()`.